# Flexdashboard into Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

I am trying to adapt the `RMarkdown` file with *.rmd extension into Shiny application. My file has elements of Shiny but works with `flexdashboard`. Below you can see the code.

````
---
title: "Test"
author: " "
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    social: menu
    source_code: embed
runtime: shiny
editor_options: 
  markdown: 
    wrap: 72
---



# Module 1

```{r global, include=FALSE}
library(biclust)
data(BicatYeast)
set.seed(1)
res <- biclust(BicatYeast, method=BCPlaid(), verbose=FALSE)

```



## Inputs {.sidebar}

```{r}
 selectInput("clusterNum", label = h3("Cluster number"), 
    choices = list("1" = 1, "2" = 2), 
    selected = 1)
```



## Row {.tabset}


### Parallel Coordinates

```{r}
num <- reactive(as.integer(input$clusterNum))

renderPlot(
  parallelCoordinates(BicatYeast, res, number=num()))

```

### Data for Selected Cluster

```{r}

renderTable(
  BicatYeast[which(res@RowxNumber[, num()]), which(res@NumberxCol[num(), ])]
)

```
````

The shiny app usually has two main parts first is `ui` and second is `server`, so can anybody help how to solve this problem and run this file as a Shiny app.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
library(shiny)
library(biclust)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("clusterNum",
    label = h3("Cluster number"),
    choices = list("1" = 1, "2" = 2),
    selected = 1
  ),
  plotOutput("plot"),
  tableOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  set.seed(1)
  data(BicatYeast)
  res <- biclust(BicatYeast, method = BCPlaid(), verbose = FALSE)

  num <- reactive(as.integer(input$clusterNum))

  output$plot <-
    renderPlot(
      parallelCoordinates(BicatYeast, res, number = num())
    )

  output$table <-
    renderTable(
      BicatYeast[which(res@RowxNumber[, num()]), which(res@NumberxCol[num(), ])]
    )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: I tried and thank you for that. But I wonder why the drop-down menu and also tabset is missing?

Comment: The drop down menu is now at the 'cluster number' input filed at the top. The tabset is missing, because this is now a shiny app and not a flexdashboard anymore like requested